# Classes in case statements

Tags: ruby, class, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm unable to determine why these two functions behave differently.  I could just use symbols or my own constants, but I have a deep desire to know what's going on here (and if I'm doing something bad).

```
def convert(value, type)
    case type
    when Integer
        value.to_i
    when String
        value.to_s
    else
        value
    end
end

def convert_with_if(value, type)
    if (type == Integer)
        value.to_i
    elsif (type == String)
        value.to_s
    else
        value
    end
end

n = 4.4
p convert(n, Integer)  #=> 4.4
p convert_with_if(n, Integer) #=> 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case` calls `===`, the case equality operator. [`Module#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D), and by extension `Class#===`, actually tests if the given argument's class is the receiver or is one of its descendants. `String === object` is practically equivalent to [`object.kind_of? String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-kind_of-3F).

```
convert 1, String
```

Would be equivalent to:

```
case String
  when Integer
    1.to_i
  when String
    1.to_s
end
```

That's like asking `is the String class an Integer?`, or `is the String class a String?`. The answer to both questions is `No, it is a Class.`.

In terms of code, `String.class` returns `Class`, which is not related in any way to `Integer` or even `String` itself. If you introduced a `when Class` or `when Module` clause, it would be executed every time.

Answer (score 1):

In your *convert* function you are getting the type `Integer` which is `Class`. That's why it's different from what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The `convert` method is not matching anything and defaulting to the `else` which is why you get 4.4.

Also, if you expect the method to output `4.4` then you would need to use decimal and not integer.